# How to keep h2 tag centered while using bounceInDown class?

Tags: html, css, center, h2, animate.css

Basically I have an h2 tag that is centered but whenever I add the bounceInDown class from animate.css it makes the text in h2 not centered. I need the text in the h2 tag to stay centered while still having the bounceInDown class in use.

example of what it should look like:
[image]

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: aquamarine; 
  font-family: Raleway;
  opacity: .86;
  font-size: 3em;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

h2>span {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: .4em;
  margin-top: -.4em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
    transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
  from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
    transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="animated bounceInDown">
  Al-Saba<span>.net</span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);`

```css
body {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  color: aquamarine; 
  font-family: Raleway;
  opacity: .86;
  font-size: 3em;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 7%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

h2>span {
  margin-left: auto;
  font-size: .4em;
  margin-top: -.4em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
    transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
  from, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
    transform: scale3d(.3, .3, .3);
  }

  20% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1.1);
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
    transform: scale3d(.9, .9, .9);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
    transform: scale3d(1.03, 1.03, 1.03);
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
    transform: scale3d(.97, .97, .97);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

@keyframes bounceInDown {
  from, 60%, 75%, 90%, to {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
  }

  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
  }

  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
  }

  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
  }

  90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
  }

  to {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.bounceInDown {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
  animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="animated bounceInDown">
  Al-Saba<span>.net</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: This is what I originally had but it doesnt work when I add the bounceInDown class.

Comment: Did you change anything in the bounceInDown class?

Comment: @OpticLukie nope, just added those 2 properties.

Comment: @OpticLukie do you need `position: absolute` on that element? If you remove that, the text will center, too.

Comment: Yeah I need the position to be absolute because if it isnt it kinda messes up the websites layout.

Comment: Not sure why it centers on yours, but not on mine.

Comment: @OpticLukie word up. then `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` is probably the best way to do it. that technique and some others are covered on this page https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: @OpticLukie I don't see it in your code. feel free to re-do it and share it with me and I'll see if I can see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I just created a div around the h2 tags and added the animate.css classes to the div. But thanks for the help!